# Fixed navbar issues

Tags: php, html, css, navbar, fixed

I'm new into web development, and i'm trying the best way I can to release my first website.
My first question into stack overflow today is that I'd like a fixed navbar. The one I've made is working... Only on Chrome. For what's about Firefox and Safari, it adds a margin-top out of nowhere and I can't figure ou how to fix it. Is there any css rule I've wrote that's not compatible with these browsers ? I didn't add any media query rule yet.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
  clear: both;
}

body {
  background: url('../img/img_fond.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  clear: both;
}

.logo {
  width: 128px;
  height: 127px;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0 !important;
  z-index: 7;
}

.dot {
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Navbar */

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #364D5C;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 7px 0px rgba(54, 77, 92, 0.7);
  margin: 0 !important;
  z-index: 6;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Links */

li {
  display: inline;
}

/* unvisited link */

a:link, a:visited {
  color: rgb(243, 240, 240);
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
}

/* mouse over link */

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* selected link */

a:active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="./index.php">
        <img class="logo" src="./img/logo/logo.svg" alt="Logo de l'association Amitie Cevenole">
    </a>
   
    <nav>

        <!-- Logo de l'association -->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="./index.php">ACCUEIL</a>
            </li>

            <span class="dot"></span>
            <li>
                <a href="./apropos.php">NOTRE ASSO</a>
            </li>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <li>
                <a href="./sejours.php">NOS SEJOURS</a>
            </li>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <li>
            <li>
                <a href="./inscription.php">S'INSCRIRE</a>
            </li>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <li>
                <a href="./actualites.php">NOTRE ACTUALITE</a>
            </li>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <li>
                <a href="./contact.php">
                    CONTACT
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

[Safari & Firefox navbar result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMF46.png)
[Google navbar result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE6v6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add some global resets into your css.
check out this github it has instructions on how to download
alternatively you can click on the "normalize.css" file shown in the "master" branch and copy and paste all of that code in your css file
github.com/necolas/normalize.css

Could also check this resource out... maybe it would help clear some things up
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/WebKit_Extensions

alternatively maybe try adding margin-top: 0; where you don't want one
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin